# EJB over HTTP: Intercepting requests and responses

Tags: wildfly, cdi, ejb-3.1, httpsession

WildFly supports remote EJB calls via HTTP. Is it possible to intercept these requests and responses in order to manipulate them? Say I want to add a session ID / conversation ID to each/most request on the client side and read them on the server side to manually active @SessionScoped and @ConversationScoped on during EJB calls. Is that possible? For example, I would guess that there a particular Servlet on the server side which handles these calls and for which I could configure a filter.

Comment: This sounds like a http://www.xyproblem.com. and a design flaw in your application. And why not pass it on as an explicit parameter?

Comment: Because that would require changing the interfaces of all EJBs that would want to use the session. And I'll have to keep changing interfaces when I decide in the future that more EJBs need to have access to session data. Since the number of EJBs in the application in question is quite high, this is simply too much.